# JSON.net JObject Adds as GrandChild instead of Direct Child

Tags: c#, json.net

If there was a Cast or partial copy from JObject to JProperty I would not be asking this question.

A JObject.AddAsChild(otherJObj) would also work if it existed.

The following snippet produces a GrandChild FavoriteFruit property but I desire a Direct Child FavoriteFruit.  The FavoriteFruit.FavoriteFruit double deep property is not what I am trying to do.

I control all the code in my situation.

The detail that makes the most obvious solution not work in my case is that I only get the final JObject to represent “FavoriteFruit” – I do not have runtime access to what generated that specific Favorite Fruit JObject instance.

```
 JObject childFavoritFruitJObj = new JObject(); // child JObject
 if (true)
 {
     JProperty childFruitNameJProp = new JProperty("FruitName", "Pear");
     JObject childFruitInfoJObj = new JObject();
     childFruitInfoJObj.Add(childFruitNameJProp);
     childFavoritFruitJObj.Add("FavoriteFruit", childFruitInfoJObj);
     // only JObject childFavoritFruitJObj remains in scope
 }

 JObject parentPersonTopJObj = new JObject(); // Final Parent JObject
 JProperty parentPersonNameJProp = new JProperty("PersonName", "John Doe");

 parentPersonTopJObj.Add(parentPersonNameJProp);
 parentPersonTopJObj.Add("FavoriteFruit", childFavoritFruitJObj);  // INCORRECT  

 Console.WriteLine(parentPersonTopJObj.ToString());

 // Final Result - Not As Desired
 //   There are TWO "FavoriteFruit" Objects
 //   FavoriteFruit is a GRAND CHILD not a Child as wanted
 // {
 //   "PersonName": "John Doe",
 //   "FavoriteFruit": {
 //     "FavoriteFruit": {
 //       "FruitName": "Pear"
 //     }
 //   }
 // }
 //
```

**This next code is the Accepted Solution for this specific case.**

```
   // This is the undesired BAD scenario - this was the original question
   parentPersonTopJObj.Add("FavoriteFruit", childFavoritFruitJObj);

   // This is the accepted SOLUTION proposed below by Sailesh 
   JProperty propFirst = null;
   propFirst = (JProperty)childFavoritFruitJObj.First;
   parentPersonTopJObj.Add(propFirst);

   // the above works in my specific case as I am guarnteed 
   // a single property name at the top of my JObject.  If you had 
   // multiple Properties at the top this would not work.;
```

The Overloaded `.Add` Operator has a single param property version that does not create the grand child scenario.  More importantly Sailesh showed me how to get the JToken Object out with `.First`

Comment: What is the expected output you are looking for?

Comment: I desire one FavoriteFruit object.  I want to remove one level of nesting from the FavoriteFruit output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access child using First, Next and Last Properties of JObject.

```
parentPersonTopJObj.Add(childFavoritFruitJObj.First);
```

Hope this line helps what you need.

Comment: This manipulates the input to get the desired results.   Your solution seems obvious but in my situation I cannot manipulate the original JObject before it comes out of the previous call.  I am looking for a way to add a JObject  as a child to an existing JObject.  In your solution you are not using the childFavoritFruitJObj.  I could manipulate childFavoriteFruitJObj after it comes out of the call and before I .Add() it

Comment: modified my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the persistence in looking into this a second time.  It is really appreciated.